# ¿Cómo programar un botón para que me pueda actualizar un registro en específico?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

El problema es el siguiente: hay una tabla que contiene los registros de personas que se inscriben en un curso se identifican sus datos y al finalizar la tabla hay una pregunta (**Confirmar Asistencia**) en ella hay dos opciones (si y no). Al teclear cualquiera de las dos opciones se actualiza la tabla y conforma si la persona asistió o no, el detalle con el que me encuentro es que no hallo como recoger el valor de cada registro para después manipularlo y actualizar la base de datos.

El código es el siguiente.

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach ($filas as $fila){ 
          $contador ++;
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$contador."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['taller']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nombre1']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['apellido1']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['cedula']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['EST_DESCRIPCION']./*"</td>
                    <td>".$fila['MUN_DESCRIPCION']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['PAR_DESCRIPCION']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['direccion'].*/"</td>
                    <td>".$fila['fecha_ini']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['fecha_fin']."</td>";        
            echo "<td>
                    <center>
                      <div class='btn-group btn-group-toggle' data-toggle='buttons' id='opciones'>
                        <label class='btn btn-outline-success btn-sm img_circle' onclick='opcion_si()'>
                          <input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='option1' value=".$fila['id_asistencia']." id='si'> SI
                        </label>
                        <label class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm' onclick='opcion_no()'>
                          <input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='option2' value=".$fila['id_asistencia']." id='no'> NO
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </center>
                  </td>";
            echo "<tr>";             
          };?>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

<script> 
  //var si=null;
  //var no=null;
  function opcion_si()
  {
  //var si = document.getElementsByName("asistencia").value;
  //var si=document.getElementById("si").value;
  //var si=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  //var si=document.getElementsByClassName("formulario")[0].value;
  var si=document.getElementsByName("asistencia")[0].value;
    $.post({var:si},function(data){
      $("opciones").html(data);
    });
    alert("si: ");
  }

  function opcion_no()
    {
      //alert("Has Hecho Click en NO");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Por registro te estas refiriendo al registro de la DB? el codigo que mostraste no hace nada de lo que decis. Cual seria exactamente el problema?

Comment: lo que quiero es recojer el value para luego mediante ese valor realizar el ajax para modificar el registro

Comment: ya solucione lo del value, en la funcion que esta en onclick le pase un parametro el cual es nada mas y nada menos que el id de cada registro, luego lo recojo en el script

Comment: como sugerencia, en este caso estas hablando de cambiar si por no y no por si (dependiendo del caso). Eso es una funcion toggle. Podrias hacer un unico checkbox (en lugar de dos radiobutton) y si esta marcado, ponerle SI, si no esta marcado, poner NO.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

1.- cuando creas el boton correspondiente, en la parte donde defines la funcion click, pasale como parametro el id de ese registro:

```
    echo "<td>
            <center>
              <div class='btn-group btn-group-toggle' data-toggle='buttons' id='opciones'>
                <label class='btn btn-outline-success btn-sm img_circle' onclick='opcion_si(".$fila['id_asistencia'].")'>
                  <input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='option1' value=".$fila['id_asistencia']." id='si'> SI
                </label>
                <label class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm' onclick='opcion_no(".$fila['id_asistencia'].")'>
                  <input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='option2' value=".$fila['id_asistencia']." id='no'> NO
                </label>
              </div>
            </center>
          </td>";
    echo "<tr>";
```

**nota**: como no defines que tipo de id es el de la fila, he supuesto que es numerico. Si fuera una cadena, deberás añadir las comillas correspondientes para pasarlo como cadena.

2.- en la parte de javascript, recuperalo definiendolo en los parametros de la funcion:

```
  function opcion_si(id_fila){
   ...
  }

  function opcion_no(id_fila){
   ...
  }
```

ahora en tus funciones javascript opcion_si y opcion_no, tienes el parametro id_fila, que puedes utilizar en tu ajax.

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta, y fue exactamente lo que que hice y funciono perfectamente muchas gracias.....

Comment: Si te ha servido marca la respuesta como aceptada